# abline() function not showing a line in plot

Tags: r, lm

Attempting to plot a line of best fit along with my data set in R. The data was imported from a .csv file.

Everything seems to work properly except for the abline() function.

```
Data=read.csv("R/SpecArea.csv")
Data

new=log10(Data)
new

fit=lm(new)

fit

plot(new)
abline(fit)
```

Thanks for any help.

This is the output of the entire program:

```
Data=read.csv("R/SpecArea.csv")
Data
    area species
1  44164      79
2  29979      79
3   4411      68
4   3423      54
5    583      34
6    385      41
7    305      40
8    233      44
9    160      16
10   133      38
11   120      22
12   108      23
13    80      29
14    71      29
15    68      21
16    62      22
17    38      24
18    33      17
19    32      24
> 
> new=log10(Data)
> 
> new
       area  species
1  4.645068 1.897627
2  4.476817 1.897627
3  3.644537 1.832509
4  3.534407 1.732394
5  2.765669 1.531479
6  2.585461 1.612784
7  2.484300 1.602060
8  2.367356 1.643453
9  2.204120 1.204120
10 2.123852 1.579784
11 2.079181 1.342423
12 2.033424 1.361728
13 1.903090 1.462398
14 1.851258 1.462398
15 1.832509 1.322219
16 1.792392 1.342423
17 1.579784 1.380211
18 1.518514 1.230449
19 1.505150 1.380211
> 
> fit=lm(new)
> 
> fit

Call:
lm(formula = new)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)      species  
     -3.508        3.941  


 plot(new)
 abline(fit)
```

Sorry for the poor formatting... I’m posting on a mobile device

Comment: May you produce the output of fit? Are you sure is working propoerly?

Comment: yes I added it too the question. I am not positive that it is working properly. The values do seem off, is it possible that running the lm() function on my data is not the proper way of doing things?

Comment: It seems likely to me, that my problem is occurring because I have not properly labeled the vectors that would be making up my dataset. Is it possible to turn the columns of my data table into vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation for `fit` is not matching your plot statement. `lm(new)` is assuming "species" is the independent variable while `plot(new)` is assuming "area" is.

Try using this:

```
fit<-lm(species ~ area, data = new)

#Call:
#lm(formula = species ~ area, data = new)

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)         area  
#     1.0223       0.2002
```

[image]

Comment: In this instance does the lm() function define species and area? When I have tried utilizing those in the past, it states that they are not recognized. Are you able to do this because of the last line of “data=new” part of the function?

Comment: Yes, the data option in lm specifies the data frame so you can just specify the column names in the formula.   Otherwise one would need to use new$area & new$species.